# Bounding the norm of the difference between two related probability densities

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, density-function, bounds, inequality

Suppose we have a continuous random variable $X$ and two continuous functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are continuous random variables. Let $p_A$ be the probability density function of a random variable $A$.

I would like to bound the norm of the difference in probability densities $p_{f(X)}$ and $p_{g(X)}$ in terms of the difference between $f$ and $g$. For example, is it possible to obtain something like this
$$
||p_{f(X)} - p_{g(X)}||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)} \le C ||f-g||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)},
$$
where $C$ might have a dependence on $p_X$? Is it possible to get some kind of bound on the norm like this?

Comment: Applying a continuous function $f$ to a continuous random variable $X$ isn't guaranteed to produce a continuous random variable.  A simple counterexample is the continuous function $f(x)=0.$ Other examples are obtained by letting $f$ be constant on any set where $X$ has positive probability.  This indicates (1) you need to be more restrictive in your assumptions and (2) your program of finding a bound is unlikely to be successful.

Comment: @whuber Yes that was sloppy of me, I've edited the question now to fix that.

Comment: @whuber In the simple case when $f(x) = \alpha x$ and $g(x) = \beta x$, we get $$\begin{align} ||p_{f(X)} - p_{g(X)}||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)} & =  ||p_{\alpha X} - p_{\beta X}||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}  \\ & = \int \bigg| \frac{1}{|\alpha|}p_X(x/\alpha) - \frac{1}{|\beta|}p_X(x/\beta) \bigg|^2d x \end{align} $$

Comment: Unless I've missed something, it doesn't look like we can bound this in terms of something like $C |\alpha - \beta|$. Although maybe we can if we have an explicit expression for $p_X$.

Comment: Densities are very unstable. Let's say $f$ is just the identity. $g$ can map a pretty small set, let's say $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$ on something even much smaller like $[x-\delta,x+\delta]$ with $\delta$ just about larger than zero but much smaller than $\epsilon$ (e.g., $\epsilon=0.1, \delta=10^{-100}$), without deviating from $f$ much really, but this will make the density in $[x-\delta,x+\delta]$ explode in case there's enough probability mass in $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$. I'd expect this can also carry the $L_2$-norm of the density differences beyond all bounds.